Money division based on partial game results
Sandeep and Varun are playing a series of games. Each of them contributes Rs $1000$ to start. Varun's chance of winning an individual game is $3$ times that of Sandeep's. They make an agreement that whoever wins $5$ games first can take the entire money with him. After first $3$ games, Varun has won $1$ game and Sandeep has won $2$ games. Now they are bored and do not want to play further. So they want to divide the money on the basis of the result of first 3 games. Let $x$ be the money Varun gets and $y$ be the money Sandeep gets. How to find values of $x$ and $y$.
This is what I have tried:
After finding probabilities of Varun and Sandeep winning each game, I found the probabilities of Varun winning the $5$ matches first. Then I thought $x$ = $2000$ times $P$(Varun winning the $5$ games given first $3$ matches) and the remaining amount is $y$.
Is this approach correct?

A somewhat peculiar problem. From where have you got it ? What topics have you studied ? From which chapter/topic does this question come ?

This is one of the questions in Erdos website (a math platform developed by IIT Roorkee).  Please find the question here: https://erdos.sdslabs.co/problems/18 .

the direction looks fine to me, so what calculations have you done?

I've considered all the cases after 3 matches where V can win the entire money and summed up the probabilities of all cases. I didn't do it for S because I feel its equal to ($1$-previous thing) as they split the whole money among themselves and dont leave anything behind.

This is a very interesting problem, and overnight I have come to a different way of thinking

We have to realise that it is a new game with new rules, starting from $Varun /Sandeep $ having won $1/2$ games respectively.
P(Varun wins a game) $=\frac34 = p$ (say)
P(Sandeep wins a game) = $\frac14 = 1-p =q$ (say)

$\underline{\texttt{Varun wins}}$
Varun needs to win $4$ games befor Sandeep wins $3$ with the final game obviously won by Varun, depicted as $- V - V - V - \Large{V}$
Sandeep can win anything from $0-2$ wins in the gaps before the match winning game. By stars and bars, if Sandeep wins $n$ games, they can be fitted into the gaps in $\binom{n+4-1}{4-1}$ ways, i.e. $4,10$ ways apart from $1$ way with $0$ wins
Thus P(Varun wins) $p^4(1+4q +10q^2) = \frac{1701}{2048}$
$\underline{\texttt{Sandeep wins}}$
Similarly, we have $-S-S-\Large {S}$
and similarly applying applying stars and bars,
Varun can have $1 , \binom32 ,\binom42 ,\binom52$ ways for inserted wins, giving
P(Sandeep wins) $= q^3(1+3p +6p^2 +10p^3) = \frac{347}{2048}$
Note that the probabilities for the new game sum up to $1$ (both probabilities were computed to confirm this)
I leave the computation of the respective prizes to you.

I have tried in the same way. So I think the second term, $p^3.\binom{4}{3}q^1$ doesn't justify the condition of "those who win 5 games first takes all the money" because in these 4 sub-cases of the $2^{nd}$ term (where S wins 1 time, V wins 3 times), we also have a case where V wins all three before S wins that 1 game, then V has won 5 games before S. Then, S wouldn't play the next match. So, I think we should consider the cases where V must win the last match. Similarly we have the other terms as well.

@NagaSaiPrajith: I have had new thoughts, looked at the problem differently, I believe it is now "pucca" !

Thank you so much! It helped me a lot. I was doing the same but I did a silly calculation mistake.

You're welcome ! Hopefully you find this method simpler.

One can encode each match as a series of 0's and 1's, where a 0 indicates that S won the game and a 1 indicates that V won the game. This code has between 5 and 9 binary digits. There are 252 matches assuming that these binary strings have either 5 0's and 4 or less 1's (and S gets the money) or 5 1's and 4 or less 0's (and V gets the money). Note that 252 is entry 5 in https://oeis.org/A000984; if a match ends if the winner has won 6 games first, then 924 matches are possible etc.
There are 126 matches where S wins with 5 games, 126 matches where V wins with 5 games, 126+126=252.
Among the 126 where S wins with 5 games, 1 match has 0 games out of 5 won by V, 5 matches have 1 game out of 6 won by V,
15 matches have 2 games out of 7 won by V, 35 matches have 3 games won out of 8 by V, and 70 matches have 4 games out of 9 won by V.
These are the binomial coefficients obtained with the stars-and-bars method. 1+5+15+35+70=126.
Each match has a probability p which is the product of 1/4 for each 0 in the string (S won) and 3/4 for each 1 in the string (V won). If one sums the probabilities of these matches over all 252 complete matches we have a probability of 6413/131072 =0.04892... that S gets the money and a probability of 124659/131072 =0.95107.. that V gets the money.
Apparently (although that is not specified in the question), the task is to find a "fair" method on the conditional probability on all matches that start with 2 zeros and one 1, i.e. encoded as 001 or 010 or 100.
Because the games are independent, we may assume that the games started 100. In that case the probability of S getting the money (after the full match) is 347/2048 = 0.1694... and of V getting the money is 1701/2048 = 0.8305.... One might say that the expected probability of S getting the money has almost quadrupled after that particular outcome of the first 3 games, but is still less than 17%. The fair division of the money after that partial match would be 347/1701 .
Here is the Maple code for this:
# count how many val are in the list L of zeros and ones.
ct0 := proc(L,val)
        local i,ct ;
        ct :=0 ; 
        for i in L do 
                if i = val then
                        ct := ct+1 ;
                end if;
        end do:
        ct ;    
end proc:

# construct all games (list of zeros and ones) where 0=S wins, 1=V wins
# and the first games already known start with the list L.
# Parameter w is the number of wins to end the match, here w=5.
play := proc(L,w)
        local L1,L0 ;
        if ct0(L,0) < w and ct0(L,1) < w then
                # if the match is not yet complete, append
                # either a 1 or a 0 and recursively construct the matches
                L1 := procname( [op(L),1],w ) ;
                L0 := procname([ op(L),0],w ) ;
                return([ op(L1),op(L0)]) ;
        else
                # if there are either already w ones or w zeros,
                # the match is finished.
                return [L] ;
        end if;
end proc:

# compute the probabiliy that the match encoded as L occurs,
# discardign the first disc entries (conditional probability)
win := proc(L,disc)
        local p,i;
        p :=1 ;
        for i from 1+disc to nops(L) do
                if op(i ,L) = 0 then
                        p := p/4 ;
                else
                        p := p*3/4 ;
                end if;
        end do:
        p;
end proc:

# construct all matches with 5 wins needed to get the money.
allL := play([],5) ;
p0 :=0 ;
p1 :=0 ;
for g in allL do
        print(g) ;
        thisp := win(g,0) ;
        if ct0(g,0) > ct0(g,1) then
                p0 := p0+thisp ;
        elif ct0(g,0) < ct0(g,1) then
                p1 := p1+thisp ;
        else
                error "same ct0",g ;
        end if;
end do:
p0 ; p1 ; evalf(p0) ; evalf(p1) ;

# construct all matches with 5 wins needed to get the money but
# already 3 first games ended in 1,0,0.
allL := play([1,0,0],5) ;
p0 :=0 ;
p1 :=0 ;
for g in allL do
        print(g) ;
        thisp := win(g,3) ;
        if ct0(g,0) > ct0(g,1) then
                p0 := p0+thisp ;
        elif ct0(g,0) < ct0(g,1) then
                p1 := p1+thisp ;
        else
                error "same ct0",g ;
        end if;
end do:
p0 ; p1 ; evalf(p0) ; evalf(p1) ;



I didn't get why there were 252 total matches. Could you please explain again?

...added to the answer...
